# Sinch Voip Calling No Response

Tags: android, sinch

I'm using Sinch to make a Voip Calling application. I'm using App to Phone call. When I click on the button to call the number there is no response. I've watched a video as well but unfortunately unable to make the code work. I don't understand from where I can get the user ID. I've entered the App key, App Secret and Environment but I don't know from where I can get the User id.

Is the code not working because of User id? Or Is there some other problem in the code?

Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NkvyD6AQdfY&t=12s

Code:

```
final SinchClient sinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder()
            .context(this)
            .userId(USER_ID)
            .applicationKey(APP_KEY)
            .applicationSecret(APP_SECRET)
            .environmentHost(ENVIRONMENT)
            .build();

    sinchClient.setSupportCalling(true);
    sinchClient.start();

    callState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.callState);
    callButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.callButton);

    callButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (call == null) {
                call = sinchClient.getCallClient().callPhoneNumber(PHONE_NO);
                call.addCallListener(new SinchCallListener());
                callButton.setText("Hang Up");
            } else {
                call.hangup();
            }
        }
    });

private class SinchCallListener implements CallListener {
    @Override
    public void onCallEnded(Call endedCall) {
        call = null;
        callButton.setText("Call");
        callState.setText("");
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallEstablished(Call establishedCall) {
        callState.setText("connected");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Call Established  "+call.getDetails(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallProgressing(Call progressingCall) {
        callState.setText("ringing");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Ringing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onShouldSendPushNotification(Call call, List<PushPair> pushPairs) {
    }
}
```

Comment: When first time you install demo app. It asks for login with `userName`. that is your `user_id` . When you will call it asks for enter `user_name` or `id` to make call. you have to enter a registred `user_name`. While making call.

Comment: Where Can i register for user id? I've watched a tutorial from youtube. He just wrote the code and called. I'm adding a link to of the video in the description

Comment: You can download demo Source code for android from this link https://www.sinch.com/downloads/

Comment: what does the logcat say

Comment: I've downloaded the tutorial

Comment: There was no error in logcat

Comment: What's the problem you are facing now?

Comment: I've solved the problem but facing another problem.Can you help me with that If I tell you about that problem?

Comment: Yes please let me know problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51493471/sinch-app-to-app-calling-sound-in-one-phone-only

Comment: Above is the link to my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As sukhbir says, download official demo app, or follow official tutorial [Link](https://www.sinch.com/downloads/). I suspect its either you don't have any money on your account, or you are clicking on the call `Button` before the client is started.

Comment: You're missing the rest of `https` on the link for the tutorial.

Comment: I didn't know at the time that the money is required for app to phone call.